# what is the easiest method to diplay a 1 to many relationship with asp.net?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, datalist

I am writing an scheduling webapp where there's:

- appointment table
- usercontact table
- technician table
- appointment2usercontact table that matches appointment_id to usercontact_id
- appointment2technician table that matches appointment_id to technician_id

So each appointment will have at 0..* contacts, and 0..* techicians assigned to them.

Each day there will be many appointments, which will be grouped by the vehicle that has been assigned to the appointment.

After some reading, I believe datalist is most appropriate for this job, but I am unsure of how I will be implementing the diplay portion.

How can I best make use of the available vs.net 2010 components to allow me to display and edit them?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdzoL